# Content overflowing outside a div when using position:absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

I have a css grid layout with 4 images with a gradient overlay and text on top of the images, when I resize the window the text goes out of the image div. This is how I want it to be even if the window gets resized - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg8fW.jpg, but the text overflows like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZiSF.png. I want the text to get resized and remain in position. I couldn't create a snippet because the layout was getting messed up in it for some reason, so I have put my html and css below as a code sample.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="grid-container1">

    <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">
        <img src="images/blog11.jpg">
        <h3 class="big-img-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">
        <img src="images/blog12.png">
        <h3 class="small-img-content">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item-3">
        <img src="images/blog13.jpg">
        <h3 class="small-img-content"></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-item grid-item-4">
        <img src="images/blog14.jpg">
        <h3 class="big-img-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Assumenda, consectetur.</h3>
    </div>

</div>

/* CSS */

.grid-container1 {
    display: grid;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 6px;
    margin: 12% auto;
}

.grid-container1 > .grid-item > img { 
    display: block;
    object-fit: fill;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 0.5px solid #858585;
}

.grid-item {
    position: relative;
}

.grid-item > .big-img-content {
    position: absolute; /* Position the background text */
    bottom: 0; /* At the bottom. Use top:0 to append it to the top */
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
    background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3) 0%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 98.73%, 0.301) 8.1%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 95.14%, 0.302) 15.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 89.6%, 0.305) 22.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 82.46%, 0.309) 29%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 74.07%, 0.313) 35.3%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 64.8%, 0.318) 41.2%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 54.99%, 0.323) 47.1%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 45.01%, 0.327) 52.9%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 35.2%, 0.332) 58.8%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 25.93%, 0.337) 64.7%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 17.54%, 0.341) 71%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 10.4%, 0.345) 77.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 4.86%, 0.348) 84.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 1.27%, 0.349) 91.9%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35) 100%
    );
    color: #fff; 
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 30% 35% 4% 10%; 
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid-item > .small-img-content {
    position: absolute; /* Position the background text */
    bottom: 0; /* At the bottom. Use top:0 to append it to the top */
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
    background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.3) 0%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 98.73%, 0.301) 8.1%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 95.14%, 0.302) 15.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 89.6%, 0.305) 22.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 82.46%, 0.309) 29%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 74.07%, 0.313) 35.3%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 64.8%, 0.318) 41.2%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 54.99%, 0.323) 47.1%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 45.01%, 0.327) 52.9%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 35.2%, 0.332) 58.8%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 25.93%, 0.337) 64.7%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 17.54%, 0.341) 71%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 10.4%, 0.345) 77.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 4.86%, 0.348) 84.5%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 1.27%, 0.349) 91.9%,
    hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35) 100%
    );
    color: #fff; 
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 52% 20% 4% 10%; 
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.grid-item-1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
  
.grid-item-4 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ahppen because your using the padding to align it, inside the selector:`.grid-item > .big-img-content`

`padding: 30% 35% 4% 10%;`

to align it to the center you can use flexBox:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

You can apply a little `padding-left` to have that free space at the beggining of the text.

Take care of the sizes which you are trying with, the first img, the screen hjas a with of 1700 and the second 1100, you should considerer use [media querys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to handle the `font-size` or the image size.

There is more info about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Yes, that works better than using padding. But for the smaller images the text goes outside once I resize the window below 1340 x 806 resolution. I have to use media queries for the font sizes I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If the flex box doens't work, try adding this code to your CSS:

```
html, body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You're welcome.

Comment: Wouldn't that just cut out the part of the text which goes outside the div?

Comment: That's a good questions, but up until the point where I've tried, it at least never happend to me...